# Using formula based on color of the text

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which will calculate the formula for a particular cell range. The range mentioned in formula will have numeral which will be in red color.

What I want to do is, I want the formula to ignore the cells that has "colored text".

```
Sheets("WBR45").Range("AE103").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(TP!$A$3:$D$30,99%)*24"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With Sheets("WBR45").Range("AE103")
    If .Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic Or .Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then .Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(TP!$A$3:$D$30,99%)*24"
End With
```

Comment: I tried running this code, but this does not give any result at all..the destination cell is just blank

Comment: the "destination" cell is the same as the "source" cell and they both are `Sheets("WBR45").Range("AE103")`. 1) What is its font color index? 2) After selecting it what is the formula bar content?

Comment: No, the destination cell is AE103 in sheet "WBR45" and the source cell for calculation is from sheet "TP" and the range is specified in the formula...How do i find the fontcolor index?

Comment: I mean that everything happens in the same cell: a) querying its font color index b) writing a formula in it. The font color index of a cell can be retrieved by selecting it, typing `?ActiveCell.Font.Colorindex` in the immediate window and pressing return. What's the answer to my question 2)?

Comment: To answer Ques 2 - The formula bar is empty

Comment: this means that `If .Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic Or .Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone` check returns `False`. Then there remains  to know what's the returned value of `?ActiveCell.Font.Colorindex` in the Immediate Window after having selected AE103 cell

Comment: I selected the cell and I dont see any immediate window to paste `?ActiveCell.Font.Colorindex`

Comment: ALT-F11 to open VBE editor and then CTRL+G to open Immediate Window

Comment: I got the O/P as "1"

Comment: then the cell has "colored text" in it gets ignored

Comment: But i have text in black color also...I dont understand why there is no result?

Comment: we must be not on the same page. maybe you post examples/shots

Comment: Code screenshot here - [link](https://postimg.org/image/hlh4a8xpv/) and myworkbook screenshot - [link](https://postimg.org/image/xvky24qrt/)

Comment: Why are you posting "TP" sheet screen shot? Aren't we talking about some "WBR45" sheet cells text font color?

Comment: The values will be in TP sheet and the result should come in WBR45 sheet

Comment: so the "coloring" issue is for "TP" sheet cells and not for "WBR45" one?

Comment: we were not on the same page at all!! Now back to your question from this (to me) new perspective, to my knowledge you can't filter values by their cell color in a Formula

Comment: Oh my!! But your code seemed really relevant to get the task done :(

Comment: unfortunately it only seemed!